# If a business is sold, does that mean the owner(s) get off scot-free?

Tags: contract-law, florida, ohio, civil-legal-system

Definition of scot-free
: completely free from obligation, harm, or penalty.

When we informed our customer that we were selling below cost, the reply we received was a suspension of communications. Then, in response to our inquiries, we were told that the business was sold to a woman (who had previously been a stockroom worker).

The "new owner" (if that is what she really is) claims she does not have any knowledge or business records prior to 2018. Is there a way to find out for sure if the business was really transferred?

Can the former owners simply walk-away with valuable sets of original-models we created at their request and put in their hands? Can they legally walk away with unresolved open invoices? Is there a legal recourse for such cases?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Have they not paid?

Comment: Did you have a contract with the business that required them to keep buying the goods?  If yes, then the new owner is obliged to make sure the business still does what the contract requires it to do.  If no, then either the old or new owners were free to stop buying at any time, for any reason or for no reason, and the sale is legally irrelevant.  (In that case, you were likewise free to stop selling to them at any time, if you had wished.)

Comment: Generally, US and US state law doesn't require that people or businesses behave "decently" in business unless they have previously contracted to do so.  It's a tough world.

Comment: It might help if you state what you actually lost. You have the right to raise your prices (subject to any contract) and your customer has a right to stop buying (again, subject to any contract) - there is nothing illegal or immoral about dumping a supplier. Did you supply stuff you weren’t paid for?

Comment: "Did you supply stuff you weren’t paid for?" Yes.

Comment: "Did you have a contract with the business that required them to keep buying the goods?" We had a verbal agreement to that effect. Proof is in the e-mails.

Comment: "Generally, US and US state law doesn't require that people or businesses behave "decently" in business unless they have previously contracted to do so." This business specifically marketed our product on the basis that a purchase would benefit the artisan and the artisans' families. The customer adhered to a set of Principles precluding mistreatment of their suppliers These Principles have been published on their website for at least the past ten years.

Comment: "It might help if you state what you actually lost" We lost original-model work that was specifically requested by the customer. They took our original- models and never paid for them, neither did they return them

Comment: Please. I don't understand why my Question was down-voted three times? It was asked in good faith. We had an experience that destroyed a craftswomens cooperative with a long history of creating and making quality handcrafted jewelry. Asking for a price rise was apparently the reason the customer became angry and curtailed communication. I believe they did it because they wanted to remove their capital out of the business without warning us or giving a reason. We never expected or even imagined that - after having provided perfect service and product for years - we would be treated so brutaly.

Answer (score 4):

In business dealings, you would have a contract with a company, not with its owner.

The new owner inherits both the assets and liabilities of the company.  It's up to the buyer of the business to do due diligence before buying the company.  The old owner may escape obligations to clients and suppliers once the sale of the business is complete, but the new owner could sue the old owner for fraud.

(It may be possible to escape some liabilities by declaring bankruptcy, but that's not the situation you described.  One unethical accounting trick that a company can use is to split the company into two corporations such that one branch inherits the liabilities, and it go defunct.)

Comment: I suspect, but can't prove, that this was a *sham sale* because the original owner was ashamed of his actions and wanted to avoid possible legal ramifications. When a person does something wrong, they would naturally have a heightened awarenemess of the nature and extent of their crime(s); in the case of a morally weak person, an instinct would be to run away from them.

Comment: What's your point? The entity that you're dealing with is the business, not the old owner or new owner. If you have a dispute that cannot be resolved through discussion, you gather your evidence and take the business to court.

Comment: A sham sale would be one in which the old owner is still the owner or something like that.

Comment: "If you have a dispute that cannot be resolved through discussion, you gather your evidence and take the business to court" "The customer cut communications on 17 december 2017.  Evidence is gathered. I am researching to learn if a legal suit is possible.

Comment: If the new business owner has no business records, and you go to court, that may end badly for them - if you claim you delivered goods and didn't get paid, and they have no business records showing otherwise, that will be held against them.

Comment: "What's your point? The entity that you're dealing with is the business, not the old owner or new owner. If you have a dispute that cannot be resolved through discussion, you gather your evidence and take the business to court. – " 
@200_success Jan 15 at 21:12 - Our evidence has been gathered in detail and organized. It is extensive; including complete GMAIL dialog in screenshot format. At present, I am researching what is the most effective statute for bringing this before a USA court. The great challenge however is finding an attorney who will even talk with me.

Comment: "the new business owner has no business records, and you go to court, that may end badly for them - if you claim you delivered goods and didn't get paid, and they have no business records showing otherwise, that will be held against them. – "
@gnasher729 Jan 16 at 10:04 It is exactly as you describe. We are owed for original-model work also, we would like to review the balance accounting from 2000-2017.  The continued appropriation of the images of ourselves and our children is another matter.

Comment: "A sham sale would be one in which the old owner is still the owner or something like that. – @George White Jan 15 at 22:28" I wonder if it is not a sham sale because the owners have behaved like criminals, circulating a letter to the Fair Trade stores that we are disreputable, and that somebody here may be resonsible for theft, claims that are easily disproved by the complete GMAIL dialog record we have prepared in slideshow form. As a result of shameless blacklisting, the employment of 15 artisan families was  destroyed.